# Update package which has newer versions in repos but can't be found in backports?

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates, official-repositories

While doing some coding with [taglib-ruby](https://github.com/robinst/taglib-ruby) (which requires TagLib (http ://taglib.github.io/ - sorry, I'm not allowed to post more than 2 links..)), I came across a strange problem and after a few days found out that this apparently has been fixed in TagLib 1.7.2. However, as I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, the newest available `libtag1-dev` package is of version 1.7.1. I tried updating it using `precise-backports` but no such package can be found there.

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and Linux at all, so is there any way to get a newer version ([which seems to be available for versions >12.04](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/taglib/)) from the repos? If not, what would be the "best" way to upgrade the library so I can use it with taglib-ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed my specific problem by adding the [Kubuntu Precise Backports](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/kubuntu-ppa_backports?dist=precise) which has a newer version of `libtag1-dev` (1.8-1~ubuntu12.04~ppa1).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libtag1-dev
```

Not quite sure though, if that fixes my actual problem with taglib-ruby or even breaks my system on the next update